# "Invalid state transition" response when switching from test to live

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

I have a problem with the YouTube Livestreaming API, and it is only causing a problem on one single account.

The CMS I support has a live to YouTube function that automatically schedules and delivers a livestream from our studios to YouTube as a parallel channel to our website.  We support multiple teams who all authenticate their accounts against our application to do this.

About 6 weeks ago we had a single group report that they are no longer seeing their content streaming live to YouTube.  All the other accounts, as well as our test channels, are working fine.

With the account in question we can see the livestream get created, the broadcast is created, and they are bound together.  Once the encoders are started we are able to successfully transition the stream to "TESTING" without problem approximately 10 minutes prior to the scheduled start time.  Where we are seeing the problem is in the final step where we transition the stream from "TESTING" to "LIVE" at the starting time of the broadcast.  We get a response with "(#100) Status transition not allowed" when we attempt to transition to live. Prior to this step we retrieve the lifeCycleStatus value, and it shows as "TESTING".

If a user logs into YouTube Studio at this point, they are able to manually transition the stream to live.

The fact that this is working with multiple other accounts, and all are using a common code base and app, I am concerned that there is something about the account itself that is causing this issue.  I have not been able to see any significant differences in the account settings when comparing with our test account.

Is there any way I can get further information about why the transition is failing, or something I should be specifically looking for as a potential problem?

Comment: Please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try stating more information / code.

Comment: I will be happy to clarify anything you think specifically needs to be clarified, but I am unable to release any of the production code for this.  Currently this code is working for multiple other accounts, but is only receiving the transition not allowed status from a single account on the testing to live transition.  We appear to meet all the requirements to perform the transition at that point.